# Redirecting dns ip to url locally

Tags: networking, server, dns, nginx, redirect

So I have this ip http://172.20.1.96:8080. I would like to redirect it to something like http://mywebsite.corp.com. I think I changed all the configurations that need to be changed, but I can only get into the website by typing 172.20.1.96:8080, but gets an error saying that its site can't be reached when typed in mywebsite.corp.com. I also mapped IP/hostname in the router.

P.S. I am trying to get it to work internally, no need to make it externally. 
I can also ping its ip from other server that is in same network, but not by its domain :(

I would really appreciated if someone could help! Thank you!

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
172.20.1.96     mywebsite.corp.com
```

---

```
hostname
mywebsite
```

---

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.20.1.1
search localhost
search mywebsite.corp.com
```

Comment: What is you dns server? Problem is on record on dns server. On `DNS` server you must have record, `mywebsite.corp.com A 172.20.1.96`. Give me output from "other server" on that network, if is linux os `host mywebsite.corp.com 172.20.1.1` I guess that is `172.20.1.1` your `DNS` server.

Comment: It is 172.20.1.1. Now it is redirected to mywebsite.corp.com. Thank you!

Comment: @2707974 That comment qualifies as an answer!  Please post it as one and drop me a line and I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: You have answer based on my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If from *other server* on that network, if is linux os command is `host mywebsite.corp.com 172.20.1.1`, I guess that is 172.20.1.1 your DNS server,
you can not resolve logical name to ip address, problem is on record on dns server.

On `DNS` server you must have record, `mywebsite.corp.com A 172.20.1.96`.